# lftp hangs up on "connecting" when tried to use ACTIVE mode

Tags: firewall, ftp, lftp

I need to use lftp in active mode (due to some limitations on the server side). So I have set up the following `~/.lftprc` config-file:

```
debug
set ssl:verify-certificate no
set ftp:port-ipv4 148.X.X.86
set ftp:passive-mode false
set ftp:ssl-allow false
set ftp:prefer-epsv no
set ftp:port-range 1026-1029
set net:socket-bind-ipv4 192.168.2.114
```

When I run lftp with any address I get the same problem:

```
lftp ftp.gnu.org
---- Resolving host address...
---- 2 addresses found: 2001:470:142:3::b, 209.51.188.20
lftp ftp.gnu.org:~> ls
---- Connecting to ftp.gnu.org (2001:470:142:3::b) port 21
**** connect(control_sock): Network is unreachable
---- Closing control socket
---- Connecting to ftp.gnu.org (209.51.188.20) port 21
<--- 220 GNU FTP server ready.
---> FEAT
<--- 211-Features:               
<---  EPRT
<---  EPSV
<---  MDTM
<---  PASV
<---  REST STREAM
<---  SIZE
<---  TVFS
<--- 211 End
---> USER anonymous
<--- 230-NOTICE (Updated October 15 2021):

<--- 230 Login successful.
---> PWD
<--- 257 "/" is the current directory
---> PORT 148,X,X,86,4,3
<--- 200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
---> LIST
`ls' at 0 [Waiting for transfer to complete]
```

And the client hangs up while waiting for data.
It seems that the port 4*256+3=1027 should be open and listing for data connection and if really is:

```
[root@c03 mkawka]# lsof -i -P |grep ftp
lftp      150072   mkawka    5u  IPv4 63562629      0t0  TCP c03:35266->ftp.gnu.org:21 (ESTABLISHED)
lftp      150072   mkawka    6u  IPv4 63607851      0t0  TCP c03:1027 (LISTEN)
[root@c03 mkawka]#
```

I've also check from outside if the open port is really visible (to exclude a firewall issue):

```
[mkawka@huragan ~]$ nmap 148.X.X.86 -p1024-1029 -Pn

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2022-08-24 12:28 UTC
Nmap scan report for 148.X.X.86
Host is up (0.0021s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
[...]
1027/tcp open     IIS
[...]
```

I am using lftp 4.4.8 and CentOS 7.9

Edit: I try to avoid passive mode, because on the server side there seems to be a limited pool of sockets/ports. It looks like we are competing with other users and sometimes we get the response 'passive mode refused'. We need to perform the transfer within a short time window, thus waiting for passive mode availablity is not reliable.